# Kafka + AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

Is it possible to integrate AWS Lambda with Apache Kafka ?
I want to put a consumer in a lambda function. When a consumer receive a message the lambda function execute.

Comment: You really should consider AWS Kinesis which is Kafka equivalent and integrates with Lambda natively.

Answer (score 15):

Continuing the point by Arafat. We have successfully built an infrastructure to consume from Kafka using AWS Lambdas. Here are some gotcha's:

- Make sure to consistently batch and commit while reading when consuming.
- If you are storing the batches to s3, make sure to clean your file descriptors.
- If you are forwarding the batches to another service make sure to clean the variables. Variable caching in AWS Lambda might result in memory overflows.
- A good idea is to check how much time you have left while from the `context` object in the Lambda and give yourself some wiggle room to do something with the buffer you populated in your consumer which might not be read to a file unless you call `close()`.

We are using Apache Airflow for scheduling. I hear cloudwatch can do that too.

Comment: confirmed, cloudwatch can be used to trigger a lambda which is running as a consumer. Our lambda uses confluent kafka for Python

Answer (score 7):

Here is AWS [article on scheduled lambdas](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html).

Given your Kafka installation will be running in a VPC, best practise is to configure your Lambda to run within the VPC as well - this will simplify the security group configuration for the EC2 instances running Kafka.

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/) is the AWS blog article on configuring Lambdas to run in a VPC.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is very much possible to have a Kafka  consumer in AWS Lambda function.

However note that you would not be able to invoke the lambda using some sort of notification. You will rather have to poll the Kafka topic. And the easiest way can be to use a [Scheduled Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)

Comment: do you have a suggestion about how to poll the topic using Lambda? I have a consumer deployed which is reading from a Kafka topic, but I'm unsure how to design the best approach to poll, keeping in mind time constraints on the lambda.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using managed apache kafka in AWS (MSK):

Since august 2020 you can connect AWS Managed Streaming for Kafka (MSK) as event source. Not your own installed kafka cluster but if you already uses AWS managed kafka this could be useful.

More in the announcement https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/aws-lambda-now-supports-amazon-managed-streaming-for-apache-kafka-as-an-event-source/

Screenshot from AWS Console:
[image: Screenshot of AWS Console when adding trigger from kafka cluster]

Answer (score 5):

AWS now supports "self-hosted Apache Kafka as an event source for AWS Lambda"

When you create a new Lambda, in the "Configuration" tab, click "Add trigger", you can now select and configure your self-hosted Apache Kafka.

Feel free to read more here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-self-hosted-apache-kafka-as-an-event-source-for-aws-lambda/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/kafka-smaa.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a community-provided [Kafka Connector for AWS Lambda](https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-aws-lambda).  This solution would require you to run the connector somewhere such as EC2 or ECS.